# Handling argument mismatch between C and Python

Tags: python, c, exception

When calling Python 3.4 functions through the C API, is it possible to handle the case when the wrong number of arguments is passed to a Python function?

That is, when invoking

```
PyObject *pFunc, *pArgs;
//[...]
PyObject *pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
```

with Python arguments packed into pArgs, is there a way to detect when there is a mismatch between those arguments and what the Python function is expecting?

Right now, it seems to return from Python immediately with no return values and no clue as to what went wrong.

Comment: Did you bother checking the exception?

Comment: @Ignacio - Yes, I surrounded the call to PyObject_CallObject() with try/catch.  There is no exception thrown from Python into C++.  Am I missing something?

Comment: [9th paragraph.](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html#calling-python-functions-from-c)

Comment: Does Python always return something to C++?  So, if pValue is null, then an error has occurred?  Thanks, it makes sense.

Comment: Python functions *always* return an object. If there is no object at the C level then an exception has been raised, no, uh, exceptions.